# Angular 9 - Service return/ List contain data but *ngFor is not displaying anything

Tags: angular

Here is my code example, I am trying this and got response from my API end but unable to display by *ngFor. In ngOnInit of category-list.component.ts i called service and got the data. One more thing is i use container here.

```
    //category.service.ts
    getAll(): Observable<Response> {
        return this.httpClient
            .get<Response>(this.apiUrl + '/category/' + 1 + '/' + 10)
            .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
    }

    //category-list.component.ts
    export class CategoryListComponent implements OnInit {
        @Input() pageSize = 4;
        categories: Category[] = [];
        constructor(
            public categoryService: CategoryService,
            private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
        ) {}

        ngOnInit() {
            this.categoryService.getAll().subscribe((data:Response) => {

                this.categories = data.data; 
                console.log(this.categories);
            });
        }
    } 
    //category-list.component.html
    <p>Category List</p>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let data of categories">{{data.id}}</li>
    </ul>
//category.component.html
<div class="card-body">
    <app-category-list></app-category-list>
</div>  
//data
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo? or try `<ul ngIf="categories"> your other code`

Answer (score 1):

in Angular dollar sign ($) marks observable. when you do this assignment

```
this.categories$ = data.data; // jsonObj as Category[];
```

you are assigning the result of the observable and not the Observable itself. So in this case either remove async pipe in your HTML and rename categories$ -> categories so it's not misleading plus change type to just Category[] OR in component assign categories$ like this

```
this.categories$ = this.categoryService.getAll();
```

Comment: Tried this but not working. can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: what's the issue ? I see in your code you declared categories$! - with that '!' sign. could that be the problem ? if no, pls post stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

Try outputting in your html just that variable and see what you get first.

Your code logic seems correct in general except for that part about Observable (I am not an expert). Try making these changes

```
categories: Category[] = [];


this.categoryService.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
            this.categories = data.data;
});


<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of categories">{{data.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwpzvr) demo that fetches data from an API, assigns the results to a property on a class and displays the results using `*ngFor` in the template.

Fork my demo and let us know further if your code still isn't working by providing a reproducible demo.

Worth mentioning that you should have `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';` included in the `imports` array of the `AppModule` which you likely already have.